# Changing image/textures of a SKSpriteNode with different sized images

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I have a large number of small images that I am swapping between in a SKSpriteNode object. The problem is it seems to establish a set container size and other images will stretch to fit the container. Is there a way to reset this each time? Or do I have to modify all the images to be the same size? I was hoping it could just display them as the true image size and I could keep it centered as they are all already centered as they are.

I basically just update the texture each time I do it. Is there a flag or property I am not setting correctly?

Answer (score 0):

When a SKSpriteNode is first created, its texture/image size is set. I suggest you take the largest x and y values in your animation sequence and set all pics to the same (largest) size. You can use a transparent background for each pic.